# Why List.sort use <? super E>

Tags: java, generics

Why List.sort() use `Comparator<? super E>` instead of `Comparator<? extends E>` or just `Comparator<E>`?

If a `List<E>` contains elements of type E or its sub-types, Comparator should only expect type E or its sub-types, in its compare method call.

For example: For a list of type Integer, why would I need a `Comaparator<Object>` or `Comparator<Number>` when `List<Integer>` can only have Integer or its sub-type?

This is not a duplicate question, please read discussion in comment section.

Comment: [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/2970947)

Comment: I saw those pages, they explain PECS in terms of collection, but here sort method parameter is Comparator, which is not collection.

Comment: And what is `List`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch List is a collection. My question is regarding sort method in List interface.

Comment: And what are you going to `sort` (with the `sort` method in the `List` interface)?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I will be sorting that List of type Integer. Why would I ever pass a Comparator<Number> in that sort. I expect Comparator<? extends Integer>

Comment: You would not, but in some cases you might sort a `List<Pet>` - then you need to compare `Cat`(s) and `Dog`(s) and `Goldfish`(s).

Comment: So if Cat, Dog and Goldfish extends Pet. I can have a Comparator<? extends Pet>.
Why would I need Pet<? super Pet>

Comment: Let's say you did have a `Comparator<Object>` that could compare any type of object. Wouldn't you want to be able to sort a list of integers with it? You sure would. Integers are objects, after all. A `Comparator<Object>` is an even smarter and more capable kind of comparator than one that *just* handles integers. This one can handle not just integers, but any old object!

Comment: @JohnKugelman So <? super E> in List.sort's Comapartor exists to provide a generic comaparator in an application which one can pass around in application to sort lists of several types in same hierarchy.